# What is the average time to get an accurate GPS location on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I realize the answer will most likely vary based on the desired accuracy. I'm most interested in 3km accuracy (kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers), but data for the other levels would also be useful.

I'm suppose I'm not exactly looking for the average time, but the point in time that I should move on and assume I'm not going to get any more accurate locations. In my use case, the GPS coordinates are not essential to my app, but highly useful.

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious, turn on updates as soon as you can in your the portion of your app that uses a location. While view are loading, etc, the location hardware and software can begin its work. Later when I'm ready for the fix I start a timer for 30 seconds. I've done this and often have the fix before my timeout starts counting. From what I have seen you should have a 3km accuracy in a few seconds.

Comment: @T.J. - I do exactly that, and my current timeout is 5 seconds. But my users will wait that entire timeout period if the GPS data hasn't met the accuracy requirement. So my goal is to get that 5 second timeout to be as low as possible without while still getting accurate GPS results. It's the balance between the waiting period and accurate GPS data that I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: What I have done is to put up an alert notifying the user that I am getting the location. In that alert I display the current accuracy and a countdown timer. I also give the user a button to press to continue of they feel the accuracy is good enough. If you are only waiting 5 seconds, displaying a simple activity indicator should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

At that distance, it is unlikely GPS will be used, as the OS will opt for cell tower or wifi triangulation. Therefore, the time is likely to be less than 42 seconds, which seems very high in its own right.

Although I have no specific data on this, I have observed - through testing our own app - that geolocation takes approximately between ten and twenty seconds.